# Do someone know how to retrieve a route hostname of an application running on openshift through jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, openshift, jenkins-job-dsl, openshift-enterprise

As the title said, do someone know how to retrieve a route hostname of an application running on openshift through jenkins pipeline?

I'm trying to retrieve the route hostname to put it in variable.

this is what i have done to achieve that but don't work :

```
openshift.selector("route", "${params.APPLICATION_NAME}") {
                    def dc = it.object()
                    shortname = dc.spec.host
                    echo "This is the route : $shortname"}
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you’ve written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Sorry, but you wrong and actually i found a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do that with this command below :

```
def route1 = openshift.selector("route", "${params.APPLICATION_NAME}").narrow('route').object()

echo "This the route of the application ${route1.spec.host}"
```